# How to debug Event Source in JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code in js:

```
var eventSource = new EventSource(base_url + 'files/chatgpt.php?q=' + $el.val());
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
   if(e.data == "[DONE]"){
       div.innerHTML += "<br><br>Hello";
   }
   div.innerHTML += JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].text;
};

eventSource.onerror = function (e) {
   console.log(e);
};
```

And the `onerror` executes, so I'm keep getting this in the console:

[image]

---

Also this is the PHP code I have:

```
$opts = [
   'prompt' => $_GET["q"],
   'temperature' => 0.9,
   "max_tokens" => 150,
   "frequency_penalty" => 0,
   "presence_penalty" => 0.6,
   "stream" => true,
];

header('Content-type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$open_ai->completion($opts, function ($curl_info, $data) {
   echo $data . "<br><br>";
   echo PHP_EOL;
   ob_flush();
   flush();
   return strlen($data);
});
```

Well, what's the error? how can I find it?

Comment: Can you share more details, like the error message you are facing and your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: Also, is this a PHP problem or a JS problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase That's exactly my question .. How to debug it? I have no clue what's the issue and no error I see. In where I have to look for the error message?

Comment: You should check whether the server returns any error, and you can do this in your browser's network console